If there a way to add black margins/padding to my monitor without affecting the resolution?
I have a new monitor and it has these beveled edges that makes the left and right side have these curved, faded, black gradient. It cuts away at the edges and looks worse depending on what angle I'm leaning at.
If I use Nvidia's control panel to resize the resolution.

It adds margins, but creates new issues.
I have programs that are dependent on 1920x1080 resolution and this change breaks them.
Is there a way to add black margins around the edges of my monitor while retaining the exact resolution so that I don't see those curved edges cut away what I'm looking at?
I think the old CRT monitors used to be able to do it and even let you change the position of the image on screen. My monitor only has the ability to change between 4:3 aspect ratio and 16:9. No other reshaping settings.

@John Lots of these new monitors have these beveled edges. I'm looking for a software based solution.

The best solution by far is to return the monitor and get one which does not crop corners.
The pattern of triple dots on the monitor is fixed, 1920 x 1080, in the case of the monitor you describe. To make an image fit in a smaller space, it would need to be scaled, interpolating a 1080 x 1920 image to, say, 1040 x 1849, making everything just a little lower resolution, perhaps a bit blurry.
Upscaling software is common, to make a 1080p image appear sharper on high-resolution monitor. Jongate advertises an application for "real-time video scaling".

You would need to investigate if such software can perform realtime downscaling for the entire video output, not just to a stream.
Depending on the GPU, scaled video might be slow, or skip frames.
And, as mentioned, images and videos will look less than their best.

